# How to set 'next' parameter via extra_context in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an online e-commerce system.  If the user is not logged in when placing an order, this is the view that directs them to the three options presented to them in the template: login, signup, do neither and continue the order details page.

I want to modify the url to which the user is redirected to should they choose to log in.  I want that url to be the order details page of the order they just made.

As you can see, I grab the order ID from the session, build the url with the order ID, then pack it in an extra_context dictionary.

```
def loginorsignup(request):
    if 'user_just_ordered' not in request.session:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('signup'))

    orderid = request.session['orderid']
    next = '/order/' + orderid
    extra_context = {'next': next}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Login':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('login', kwargs={'extra_context': extra_context}))
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Create New Account':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('signup'))
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Not Now':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('orderwithid', args=(orderid,)))

    return render(request, 'registration/loginorsignup.html', locals())
```

When I get to this point in the order process and click 'Login' I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /users/loginorsignup/
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant `urls.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kwargs` argument in `reverse` is used when an URLConf regex contains named groups.

Example:

```
# For a URL defined this way:
url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', my_view, name='user_detail')

# You'll use reverse this way:
reverse('user_detail', kwargs={'user_id': some_user_id})
```

What you want is to add GET parameters to your URL. Which you can achieve this way:

```
from urllib import urlencode

bare_url = urlresolvers.reverse('login')
encoded_get_params = urlencode({'next': next})
separator = '&' if '?' in bare_url else '?'
url = '{}{}{}'.format(bare_url, separator, encoded_get_params))
```